# Java com MySQL (JDBC) - Tipo YEAR

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou com uma dúvida em como gravar um tipo YEAR no banco MYSQL utilizando uma aplicação Java a partir de um TextField, já tentei utilizar tipo Date, mas não consigo pegar apenas o ano para gravar no banco no campo YEAR. tentei com SimpleDateFormat mas ele acaba gerando um novo tipo de dado que não funciona com o método preparedStatement do JDBC.

Segue abaixo diagrama do banco e a classe da Entidade e da View:

[image: Diagrama MySQL]

View:

```
 private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    Livros livros = new Livros();
    LivrosDAO livrosDao = new LivrosDAO();
    livros.setTitulo(tfTitulo.getText());
    livros.setIsbn(Integer.parseInt(tfISBN.getText()));
    livros.setAno(Short.valueOf(tfAno.getText()));
    livros.setPaginas(Integer.parseInt(tfPaginas.getText()));
    livros.setGenerosEntity((Generos) cbGenero.getSelectedItem());
    livros.setAutoresEntity((Autores) cbAutor.getSelectedItem());
    livros.setEditorasEntity((Editoras) cbEditora.getSelectedItem());
    if (tfCodLivro.getText().isEmpty()) {
        livrosDao.inserir(livros);
        livrosTableModel.addLivro(pesquisar(livros));
    } else {
        livros.setCodLivro(Integer.parseInt(tfCodLivro.getText()));
        livrosDao.atualizar(livros);
        livrosTableModel.updateLivros(linhaSelecionada, livros);
    }

    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

DAO:

```
public boolean inserir(Livros livro) {
    try {
        super.abrirConnection();
        super.preparedStatement = super.connection.prepareStatement(INSERT);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, livro.getIsbn());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, livro.getTitulo());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, livro.getAutoresEntity().getCodAutor());
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, livro.getEditorasEntity().getCodEditora());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, livro.getGenerosEntity().getCodGenero());
        preparedStatement.setShort(6, livro.getAno());
        preparedStatement.setInt(7, livro.getPaginas());
        return preparedStatement.executeUpdate() != 0;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao inserir o registro" + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        fecharPreparedStatement();
        fecharConnection();
    }

}
```

Entidade:

```
public short getAno() {
    return ano;
}

public void setAno(Short ano) {
    this.ano = ano;
}
```

Comment: Segundo a documentação, esse campo se converte no tipo `java.sql.Short` e não no `short` primitivo como você está utilizando no metodo getAno, são tipos diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado!
Funcionou

Answer (score 0):

O seu método getter `getAno()` retorna um tipo primitivo "short," que é diferente do tipo Short do `java.sql.Short`. Você deve usar o java.sql.Short, que é o tipo usado pelo driver.

> YEAR[(2|4)]   YEAR    If yearIsDateType configuration property is set to
>   false, then the returned object type is **java.sql.Short**. If set to true
>   (the default), then the returned object is of type java.sql.Date with
>   the date set to January 1st, at midnight.

Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html